# Why dont see the user_engagement event in the event report in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: firebase-analytics

-Hello,

-I would like to understand why the user_engagement event is not see in the events report.

Comment: Hi ! Please elaborate, this is a very vague question with no context at all. Also, you should be giving details in the content rather than in the title (for instance, Firebase Abalytics).

Comment: I think the question is a good one and is clearly understandable. user_engagement is listed as an auto-generated event (https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485) and it drives the engagement stats in Dashboard. I don't see it listed in the Events tab of my Firebase app, though, whereas I do see other auto-gen'd events such as app_exception, app_remove, app_update etc. Any ideas why user_engagement is not listed? The reason I'm looking is that I don't know whether '1-day' in Dashboard means 'yesterday' or 'the last 24 hours(-ish)'.